# Android webview does not show internally stored HTML fit to the screen

Tags: android, html, webview

Its just a simple text and its shown in the top left corner of AVD

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

myWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
myWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/new2.html");
```

this is xml which is very basic i'll add more widgets later once i get this this done.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   tools:context=".MainActivity" >
  <WebView android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  </WebView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post the complete xml?

Comment: if you cant see the full xml, ill paste it here. thanks mate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]I'm not sure if this is what you mean, but I think you want to show the html file and fit to screen.

I just made a project right now and it's working.

**The xml:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**The MainActivity**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

        myWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

        myWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();

        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/new2.html");
    }
```

**EDIT**
Your webview isn't the problem, it's filling the screen. It's the HTML you need to change. I'm not good at web stuff but i'm sure there is a way to fix that, but it's not Android related. In meantime you can add zoom this code to add zoom controls if you like:

```
myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true); 
myWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
```

Comment: i tried your code but my problem persists. new2.html has text only and it does not fit different screen sizes. it shows roughly on 1/3rd of the screen of an AVD for some reason.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot? Iv'e only tried this on my Galaxy S2

Comment: cheers mate! i'll try it on galaxy s2 AVD. my app is suppose to read html files stored internally. all the labels, buttons etc work fine on different screens its just the text on pages which cannot be scaled to to fit various screens. i just cannot get my head around this problem. thanks for your help.

Comment: looks like the text is zoomed out by default. i am able to zoom in by "double click" but why cant it be zoomed in by default? as zooming in indeed fits the screen.

Comment: Ok try this: In your html file put this under the title tag : `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />`

Comment: it indeed worked for a html with text only(thanks a lot for that as it is one lil berak through) however the html i am working on has pictures, buttons, labels etc which are internally stored in "asset" folder. navigation between pages is done via html code.

Comment: Moreover it works perfectly on Galaxy Note AVD but looks worst than crap on Galaxy Nexus's AVD.